# Does AppCenter update packages I have installed (such as Node.js)?

Tags: appcenter, repositories

I use elementaryOS Loki and have Node.js installed. I have noticed that Node is always up to date. AppCenter has updates almost everyday mostly under **Operating System Updates**. I wonder if it updates packages from repositories I have added to the system (currently just Git's PPA and Node's nodesource).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does update packages from PPAs too.